# 519: 132: Request for stale data Passkit IOS wallet

Tags: php, ios, silex, wallet, passkit

I'm unable to update my pass coupon seems like very less help available here. im generating dynamic coupons my endpoint in PHP. im unable to push new changes on device. after push notification device, im getting this line i don't know it is error or information but my coupon not updating.

iphone 4 IOS 9.3
`Jul  7 08:04:41 iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Error>: Could not get event name for stream/token: com.apple.backgroundtaskagent/519: 132: Request for stale data`

Iphone 6s IOS 10+

```
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libCommCenterMCommandDrivers.dylib)[81] <Notice>: #I CDRX Indication: LTE with CDRX is false
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[81] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0xe7(ELQM) Ind MsgId=0x0002 Bin=[<private>]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: eLQM: Posting RRC change notification with label = kNotificationCellLinkStateChange, state = 1, bitmask = 2, info = {
    Detail = 0;
    State = 1;
}
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: eLQM: Updated cell states (payload = <02020001 00>): (LQM = 100, RRC = 1, INTF = 1)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: RRC State change
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: 0x10021af10 foreground: 1 primary: 0 for noi: NOI: v:0 type:Cell, isAny:yes, isBuiltin:no, loi:-1, flags:0
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: 0x1005bc210 observed discretionaryTrafficInvited of object NOI: v:0 type:Cell, isAny:yes, isBuiltin:no, loi:-1, flags:0, partial update to pid: 3073, change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 1;
}
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: 0x100263ba0 observed discretionaryTrafficInvited of object NOI: v:0 type:Cell, isAny:yes, isBuiltin:no, loi:-1, flags:0, partial update to pid: 1263, change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 1;
}
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: 0x10025f530 observed discretionaryTrafficInvited of object NOI: v:0 type:Cell, isAny:yes, isBuiltin:no, loi:-1, flags:0, partial update to pid: 91, change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 1;
}
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: RRC Update to ON. mach time: 3155729169366  <0x10021af10> (NOI: v:0 type:Cell, isAny:yes, isBuiltin:no, loi:-1, flags:0)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>:  _startConnectionTimestamp: 3155729169366
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: 0x10021af10 foreground: 1 primary: 0 for noi: NOI: v:0 type:Cell, isAny:yes, isBuiltin:no, loi:-1, flags:0
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: AWD RRC Metric: noi.isAny with no foregroundActivity flag became ON (plugged in)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: 0x100221f40 foreground: 1 primary: 0 for noi: NOI: v:0 type:Cell, isAny:yes, isBuiltin:no, loi:-1, flags:1
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: 0x10021ccf0 foreground: 1 primary: 0 for noi: NOI: v:0 type:Cell, isAny:no, isBuiltin:yes, loi:0, flags:0
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 DuetHeuristic-BM(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[127] <Notice>: Trigger: <private> is now [1]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[116] <Notice>: New RRC 1 when previous 0 from pdp_ip0, epoch interface pdp_ip0
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[81] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0xe2(BSP) Ind MsgId=0xe013 Bin=[<private>]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libCommCenterMCommandDrivers.dylib)[81] <Notice>: #I CDRX Indication: LTE with CDRX is true
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[81] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Ind MsgId=0x555b Bin=[<private>]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter[81] <Notice>: #N Add Frequency List Failed
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[81] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Ind MsgId=0x555b Bin=[<private>]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter[81] <Notice>: #N Add Frequency List Failed
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[81] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0xe2(BSP) Ind MsgId=0xe006 Bin=[<private>]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libBasebandManager.dylib)[81] <Notice>: #I Sending <private> to <private> at 1499437530285
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[81] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0xe2(BSP) Req MsgId=0xe002 Bin=[<private>]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: Client /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter connected
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: no bundle ID or bundle path found - denying /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: getClientEffectiveRegistrationResult, /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter, , , CLClientRegistrationResult, kCLClientRegistrationResultFailedBlacklisted, CLCommonLocationServicesEnabled, 1
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: no bundle ID or bundle path found - denying /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: getClientEffectiveRegistrationResult, /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter, , , CLClientRegistrationResult, kCLClientRegistrationResultFailedBlacklisted, CLCommonLocationServicesEnabled, 1
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: message 'kCLConnectionMessageOnBodyDetectionParams' received from client '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter'
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: message 'kCLConnectionMessageOnBodyDetection' received from client '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter'
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: Client /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter (0x1028f3200) is subscribing to notification kCLConnectionMessageOnBodyDetection
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 locationd[2981] <Notice>: message 'kCLConnectionMessageWatchdog' received from client '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter'
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200>: Outstanding data received: <0a554120 70g1410e edfa75r3 a35ad482 35720f1a 78674sdd f05g8426 4ba77bca 759857fe 42146691 ebf6ef33 b12afd14 1ad9759e 0c0dfd3c ec8e0480 05a80106 a714cf12 7d1d1b37 ce078003 0a7b2261 7073223a 5b5d7d> (length 87) onInterface: WWAN. Connected on 1 interfaces.
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200>: Stream processing: complete yes, invalid no, length parsed 87, parameters {
    APSProtocolCommand = 10;
    APSProtocolMessageExpiry = "1970-01-01 18:12:15 +0000";
    APSProtocolMessageID = <00000000>;
    APSProtocolMessageTimestamp = 1499437529506199502;
    APSProtocolPayload = <7b226170 73223a5b 5d7d>;
    APSProtocolToken = <70g1410e edfa75r3 a35ad482 35720f1a 78674sdd f05g8426 4ba77bca 759857fe>;
    APSProtocolTopicHash = <6691ebf6 ef33b12a fd141ad9 759e0c0d fd3cec8e>;
}
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: copyTokenForDomain push.apple.com (null)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: copyTokenForDomain push.apple.com (null)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: copyTokenForDomain push.apple.com (null)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: copyTokenForDomain push.apple.com (null)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSPushHistory: 0x10032cda0> timestampForTopic? pass.client.com.companydomain token <70g1410e edfa75r3 a35ad482 35720f1a 78674sdd f05g8426 4ba77bca 759857fe>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: copyTokenForDomain push.apple.com ,66ffffff91ffffffebfffffff6ffffffef33ffffffb12afffffffd141affffffd975ffffff9e0c0dfffffffd3cffffffecffffff8e
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSPushHistory: 0x10032cda0> timestampForTopic? pass.client.com.companydomain token (null)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSPushHistory: 0x10032cda0> receivedPushWithTopic pass.client.com.companydomain token <70g1410e edfa75r3 a35ad482 35720f1a 78674sdd f05g8426 4ba77bca 759857fe> payload <7b226170 73223a5b 5d7d> timestamp 2017-07-07 14:25:29 +0000
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200>: Received message for enabled topic 'pass.client.com.companydomain' with payload '{
    aps =     (
    );
}' onInterface: WWAN  for device token: YES  with priority (null)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSMessageStore: 0x1003a8dc0> asked to store incoming message <APSIncomingMessage: 0x1003b2390> with guid 6BCG8ERE-2F97-4C87-8DSA-DA26535F5ES3 environment <APSEnvironment: 0x10030ce00: production>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200>: Calling into AWD for PushReceived
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200>: AWD for PushReceived finished
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200>: Stream processing: complete no, invalid no, length parsed 0, parameters (null)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: APSMessageStore - New message record [<APSIncomingMessageRecord 0x1003a4110 [0x1ad222bb8]>{}] has ID [48510].
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSMessageStore: 0x1003a8dc0> calling completion block for incoming message 6BCG8ERE-2F97-4C87-8DSA-DA26535F5ES3
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200>: Sending acknowledgement message with response 0 and messageId <00000000> (0)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <PCWWANUsabilityMonitor: 0x100310e90> isLTEWithCDRX? On
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSDecayTimer: 0x100412e20>:APSNetworkMonitor decaying cost (0 - 1) = 0 for 7.178882 seconds
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSDecayTimer: 0x100412e20>:APSNetworkMonitor addCost: 25 - _currentCost is now 25
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200> _notifyForIncomingMessage <APSIncomingMessage: 0x1003b2390> with guid 6BCG8ERE-2F97-4C87-8DSA-DA26535F5ES3
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: Dispatching high priority message: <OS_xpc_dictionary: <dictionary: 0x10330b140> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "message" => <dictionary: 0x1003bdb20> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
        "ECF19A18-7AA6-4141-B4DC-A2E5123B2B5C" => <data: 0x1003c54c0>: { length = 16384 bytes, contents = 0x62706c69737431351369010000000000801200000000d87f... }
    }
    "message-type" => <int64: 0x10032b510>: 30
}>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: Looking up connection on peer: 345df0   found <APSConnectionServer: 0x1004ca9a0>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200> informed that <APSConnectionServer: 0x1004ca9a0> acknowledges incoming message with guid 6BCG8ERE-2F97-4C87-8DSA-DA26535F5ES3
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSMessageStore: 0x1003a8dc0> Removing incoming message with guid 6BCG8ERE-2F97-4C87-8DSA-DA26535F5ES3
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: <APSCourier: 0x100412200> _schedulePendingWorkUpdate
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[91] <Notice>: 2017-07-07 07:25:30 -0700 apsd[91]: APSMessageStore - APSIncomingMessageRecordDeleteMessageForGUID 6BCG8ERE-2F97-4C87-8DSA-DA26535F5ES3
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Push interval 1156.94 min; zero interval = 120 min; score delta = -8.64115; new score = 0
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[81] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0xe2(BSP) Resp MsgId=0xe002 Bin=[<private>]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: New task [<private>] does not interact with any enqueued tasks
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Enqueued task [<private>] does not interact with any scheduled tasks, dequeueing
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Begin delaying exit: Archive Tasks (1)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Removing Scheduled Activity: PDNetworkTaskManagerActivateEligibleTasksActivityIdentifier for Client: <private>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Begin delaying exit: Archiving Scheduled Activities (2)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 powerd[37] <Notice>: Activity changes from 0x1 to 0x11. UseActiveState:1
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 powerd[37] <Notice>: hidActive:1 displayOff:0 assertionActivityValid:0 now:0x201a0  hid_ts:0x20101 assertion_ts:0x0
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: <private> 0x115e3fe00: Created power assertion: <private> (37784)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 UserEventAgent(com.apple.cts)[22] <Notice>: Unregistered XPC Activity: PDNetworkTaskManager.WebServiceTasks.PDNetworkTaskManagerActivateEligibleTasksActivityIdentifier
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Begin delaying exit: ActiveTasks (3)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Activating task <private>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Generating GET request with URL <<private>>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Enabled Notification Services Push Topics: <private>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Payment Web Service push topics: <private>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Applying push notification token: <private>\M-b\M^@\M-&
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Applied token: <private>
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd(CFNetwork)[148] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Start [282:0x115e3a840]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 DuetHeuristic-BM(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[127] <Notice>: CANCELED: <private>!
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd(CFNetwork)[148] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Event [282:0x115e3a840]: 1 Err(0)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd(CFNetwork)[148] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Connected [282:0x115e3a840]: Err(0)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd(CFNetwork)[148] <Notice>: TIC Enabling TLS [282:0x115e3a840]
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd(CFNetwork)[148] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [282:0x115e3a840]: 2, Pending(0)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd(CFNetwork)[148] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [282:0x115e3a840]: 11, Pending(0)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd(CFNetwork)[148] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [282:0x115e3a840]: 12, Pending(0)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd(CFNetwork)[148] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [282:0x115e3a840]: 14, Pending(0)
Jul  7 07:25:30 Iphone 6 passd[148] <Notice>: Received authentication challenge:
  ---->Protection Space: <Realm: (null), Host: <private>, Protocol: https, Method: NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust>
  ---->Proposed Credential: (null)
  Performing default handling.
```

Environment: PHP 7 - OS Linux

Framework/Project: Opensource - passbook. Github link : webservice-passbook LINK: https://github.com/xav-stargate/webservice-passbook

please help me past one week im stuck...

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: endpint webservice in PHP i already added Github link i don't know maybe im missing something in my PHP code.